# Determine Alexa users device Name/type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

While building a skill for Amazon Alexa, I would like to know the name of the device (or a code, manufacturer, etc).  This is desired for analytics.  We can get the supported interfaces from the JSON request to the webhook, but I am also interested in the exact device (Echo, Dot, show, spot, Echo Plus, Fire TV, Alexa App, Eufy Genie, etc.)

Comment: Thats not possible. As you mention, device id and supported interfaces are available (https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#context-object). But as you can also tell when reading the linked documentation, there isn't any additional information on the device type.